# different between append list to array python

Tags: python, list

Had a question regarding appending to python list. See below

```
arr1 = []
arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5]



# Method 1
arr1.append(arr2) 


# Method 2
arr1.append(list(arr2))
```

What is the difference between the both append methods above? I ran the above snippet in the python and saw the same results for both as arr1 prints [1,2,3,4,5].

Would it differ when you were to pass the list into a function and perform the same operations?

How to determine when to use # Method 1 or # Method 2?

Comment: `arr2` is a list already, so `list(arr2)` does not make a difference. Python has no built-in `array` type, both `arr1` and `arr2` are `list`

Comment: No way that prints out `[1,2,3,4,5]`.  It prints out `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]`

Comment: It _does_ make a difference in that `list(arr2)` creates a new list. Which doesn't change the result in this context but adds a small performance overhead. You would always use the first variant as the second literally the same thing with a superfluous extra step. If you assign the result to a variable, e.g. `arr3 = arr1` or `arr4 = list(arr1)`, then it does make a difference: manipulating `arr3` will also change `arr1` (as the variables point to the same object) but manipulating `arr4` will not as it's a different object.

Comment: You can devise tests for all of your questions - you should do so and see if there are any surprises. When you thought a bit about your scenarios did you have any possible pros/cons?

Comment: @shrewmouse yes you right. my mistake. both output from method 1 and method 2 would print [[1,2,3,4,5]] but I am not sure why one would use Method 1 over Method 2 and vice versa?

Comment: Seems like you should read a few tutorials on object oriented programming, because if you ask yourself what the difference is that means you don't understand how variables and references to objects work.

Comment: The difference is between putting the list `arr2` into `arr1`, and putting a *copy* of `arr2` into `arr1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They only reason to use method two is because you want to create a copy of arr2.  Changes to the copy would not affect the original.

```
Python 3.6.8 (default, Feb 14 2019, 22:09:48)
[GCC 7.4.0] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> arr1 = []
>>> arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> arr1.append(list(arr2))
>>> arr1.append(arr2)
>>> arr2[0] = 9
>>> print(arr1)
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [9, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```